# Anaconda python behind very strict firewall

Tags: python

Is it possible to download the whole [conda repository](http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-32/) using wget and use it for installations on offline machines ?

I guess by using the `-c` option I could define a new local channel `file://...` together with the `--offline` argument ?

Comment: well, I found sort of a solution. Take the notebook, connect to my network at home and do the upgrades without my companies vpn/network. It is not really compliant but it works.